# Rails app and Wordpress blog on the same server - how to configure nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a DigitalOcean droplet. There's running a Rails 5 app on nginx and PostgreSQL database. I have installed PHP, MySQL, and Wordpress (WP to the `/home/deployer/blog` directory).

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/sockets/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myapp.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    return 301 https://www.myapp.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  #listen 80 default deferred;
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

  server_name www.myapp.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public; # rails app

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location ~ ^/(robots.txt|sitemap.xml.gz)/ {
    root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https; # added because of looping
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  # I added this blog for the WP blog
  location /blog {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog /index.php?$args;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I restart nginx after modifying this config file and go to `www.myapp.com/blog`, I only receive the Rails error page saying **The page you were looking for doesn't exist.**

I found quite a lot of articles how to modify the nginx config in order to make the WP blog working on a subdomain, but still cannot find the right recipe for me.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and why nginx doesn't load WP and instead of that still only the Rails app?

Comment: You need at least define fastcgi_pass or other php proxy for php stuff. Neverthelss don't think there is straightforward aproach to do it on the same domain name, much easier with sperate domans and subdomains. Then for each you have seperate server block

Comment: Need to do the same thing. Were you able to do it ?